# Stream<Object> instead of Stream<? extends T> being produced when invoked on list

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I have this method:

```
public static <T,U,R> Stream<R> cartesian(
    List<? extends T> list1,
    List<? extends U> list2,
    BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, R> func) 
{
    return list1.stream() // list1.stream() produces Stream<Object> not Stream<? extends T>!
        .flatMap(x -> {
            return list2.stream()
                .map(appendable ->x + "" +appendable);
        });
}
```

Because of the following error, my whole pipeline now return a `Stream<Object>` instead of the intended `Stream<R>`.

Any reasons why this error occur which I arrowed occurs?

Comment: I think you want to do `.flatMap(x -> list2.stream().map(appendable -> func.apply(x, appendable)));`

Comment: `x + "" +appendable` produces a `String`, not `R`. Why don’t you use `func` to produce `R`?

Comment: Oh right, my bad, but the problem of `list1.stream()` not producing `Stream<? extends T>` is not due to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "expected type: ... actual type: ..." message is not about `list1.stream()`, it's about the value you return in the lambda in `flatMap`. Observe where the red squiggles are:

[image]

It's saying that the code in the `x -> ...` lambda is returning a `Stream<Object>`, rather than the expected `Stream<R>`.

Note that `map(spendable -> x + "" + appendable)` can totally return a `Stream<Object>` with the right type arguments ( if it were `.<Object>map(appendable ->x + "" +appendable)` for example).

And in fact, the "expected type: ... actual type: ..." message is only produced by IntelliJ, so it's probably just IntelliJ being a bit silly. If you run `javac`, you get a much better error message:

```
incompatible types: inference variable R#1 has incompatible bounds
        .flatMap(x -> {
                ^
    equality constraints: R#2
    lower bounds: R#3,String
  where R#1,T#1,R#2,T#2,U,R#3 are type-variables:
    R#1 extends Object declared in method <R#1>flatMap(Function<? super T#1,? extends Stream<? extends R#1>>)
    T#1 extends Object declared in interface Stream
    R#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,U,R#2>cartesian(List<? extends T#2>,List<? extends U>,BiFunction<? super T#2,? super U,R#2>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,U,R#2>cartesian(List<? extends T#2>,List<? extends U>,BiFunction<? super T#2,? super U,R#2>)
    U extends Object declared in method <T#2,U,R#2>cartesian(List<? extends T#2>,List<? extends U>,BiFunction<? super T#2,? super U,R#2>)
    R#3 extends Object declared in method <R#3>map(Function<? super T#1,? extends R#3>)
```

That says that the type parameter `R` in `flatMap` cannot be inferred, because its bounds cannot be satisfied simultaneously. `R` in `flatMap` has to be the same as the `R` in `cartesian`, but its lower bounds are `R` in `map`, and `String`.

Anyway, it seems like what you wanted to do was:

```
return list1.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> list2.stream().map(y -> func.apply(x, y)));
```